# PHP str_replace seems to be applying htmlspecialchars

Tags: php, str-replace, htmlspecialchars

I have a strange issue I can't seem to solve.  I am running a string replace as follows:

```
$message = str_replace("{{CODE}}", $myCode, $content["codeMessage"]);
```

The replace works fine but if `$content["codeMessage"]`contains an apostrophe, the value of `$message` is:

`Here&#039;s your login code`

It's as if htmlspecialchars is being applied automatically but I'm sending this to an application that isn't HTML aware so I need to maintain the apostrophe.  I've tried all kinds of variations and even tried running an htmlspecialchars_decode on the variable but that doesn't seem to do the trick.

Thank you!

Comment: How is `$myCode` being generated?

Comment: @Matt  Like this:  `$myCode = rand(100000, 999999);`

Comment: Something else is going on.  How are you determining that's the output? Is it in a `var_dump`, or are you doing something else?

Comment: @cale_b  I've validated that is the output through `var_dump` and echo'ing the value out to a page and viewing the page source.

Comment: you probably have the html code in $content["codeMessage"]. do a var_export($myCode); var_export($content["codeMessage"]);

Comment: @useless So a `var_export($content["codeMessage"])` seems to reveal the issue: `Here&#039;s your login code`  The value of `$content["codeMessage"]` is coming from a MySQL database but I'm looking at the raw value in the database and it isn't the special character - just a simple apostrophe??

Comment: if you are 100% sure database does not have html content, then the class that you are using to load the values should be the issue. or if you are using a mvc maybe the mvc is preprocessing your $content array to prevent html injection.